# Where to store files locally so they will not be deleted after deleting an Electron application?

Tags: node.js, windows, macos, electron

Right now I store my files right inside installed app directory and on macOS after deleting an application all saved files are gone too because they were right inside .app directory.

Where should I store files so they will not be deleted after deleting an application? Both on Windows and macOS.

For example, `electron-store` on macOS stores all data here: `~/Library/Application Support/App Name/` but I don't know where exactly it stores it on Windows.

More context:
I have an Electron app that stores images that user saves and show it inside the app. But the user shouldn't have an **easy** access to these images using any file provider because these images are the part of the database and I store paths and information about them. Hope it helps :)

Comment: It's also a good habit to provide an option to delete user data in app uninstaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically data is stored in the user’s “app data” folder where this directory is varies by operating system.

**Mac OS: ~/Library/Application Support/{Your App Name (taken from the name property in package.json)}**

**Windows: C:\Users\\AppData\Local{Your App Name}**

**Linux: ~/.config/{Your App Name}**

Electron provides app.getPath which returns the right directory, depending on your platform.

check this link for more info [electron-store-data](https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/how-to-store-user-data-in-electron-3ba6bf66bc1e)

Comment: And if I delete an application, this data will not be deleted, right?

Comment: no won't be deleted as it won't be stored along with your app